# Call function inside CodeIgniter's controller using jquery / ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Can somebody please explain to me what is the right way to call a php function with jquery / ajax in Codeigniter. Right now, this code isn't working and i cant figure out whay. Note that admin.php controler is inside admin map. Thanks in advance

html code

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="change">
             <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id_product; ?>" id="prod" >    
             <input type="submit" value="switch" >
</form>
<div class="resultdiv">
    <?php echo $data; ?>
</div>
```

my function inside admin.php controller

```
 public function do_search(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        return $id;
    }
```

Jquery AJAX script

```
$( "#change" ).submit(function() {
  alert( "Change" );
  var id = $('#prod').val();
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'admin321/do_search',
            data:{'id':id},
            success:function(data){
                $('#resultdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Config / routes.php

```
$route['admin/do_search'] = "admin_controller/admin/do_search";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that this is old post, but maybe someone will find this usefull.

I solve this problem by adding `index.php` in url. Even if the `index.php` is hidden using rewrite.

```
  $( "#change" ).submit(function() {
      alert( "Change" );
      var id = $('#prod').val();
         $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("index.php/admin/do_search"); ?>',
                data:{'id':id},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#resultdiv').html(data);
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Good job! This did it!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: what to do if there are parameters need in that function?  how do we pass it? Thank you

Comment: You can use data attribute as shown on the example where the ID is send to controller as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
    $( "#change" ).submit(function() {
  alert( "Change" );
  var id = $('#prod').val();
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url("admin/do_search"); ?>',
            data:{'id':id},
            success:function(data){
                $('#resultdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

You have to load this helper:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

@edit

```
$route['admin/do_search'] = "admin_controller/admin/do_search";
```

This code is unnecessary.

Comment: I have autoladed helper url, but somehow ajax doesn't call function right or it don't retrive data right somehow..

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I have set up a route for the ajax request. Something like this:

```
$route['admin/search/(:any)'] = 'admin_controller/admin/do_search/$1';
```

Then my ajax request would look like this:

```
var prod = $('#prod').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url:'admin/search/'+prod
    ...
});
```

Or, you can grab the form action via jQuery and use that as your url.

```
<form action="admin/search/123" method="post">

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: $('form').attr('action')
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this works. My routes file is the default.

I loaded  CI URL helper in my controller __construct() function

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Here's my ajax:

```
/*
 *Ajax function to load confirmation page
 */
var formID=$("div form");
formID.submit(function(event){        //activated on submit event
    event.preventDefault();           //stops page from reloading
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'<?php echo site_url("plan/process")?>',
        data:formID.serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            $("div #msg_area").html(data);
            window.setTimeout(function(){parent.location.reload()},3000);
        } 
    });
});
```

I have multiple controllers so it calls the specific one call plan and the \n the function process. The process function one looks like this:

```
function process (){

        $json_data = strtolower(json_encode($this->input->post()));
        $res = array();

        //Simple Error/success display...
        $res = json_decode($this->plan->process_plan($json_data ),true);
        if(array_key_exists('error',$res)){
            $window = "warning";
            $error=explode(":",$res['error']);
            $result['message']="<h2><span class='color-dark'>Submission error:</span> ".$error[0]." </h2><p>".$error[1]."</p>";
        }
        else{
            $window = "success";
            $result['message'] = "<h2>Submission was a success</h2>";
        }
        echo $this->load->view("common/components/".$window,$result);


    }
```

This works great for me. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

in your routes file you have: `admin321/do_search` NOT: `admin/do_search`

You can also try using the absolute path:

```
`http://www.website.com/admin/do_search` or `http://localhost/admin/do_search`
```

in the ajax url parameter

Comment: Nop, sorry, this didn't do it.